# Repeat an age and sex input from first survey encounter for repeated patient survey

Tags: r, replace, fill

I am working with a large dataset with repeated data surveys for patients. The patients were only surveyed about asked about their sex and age in the first instance of the survey and I am looking to replace the N/A values for the follow-up surveys with the first recorded instance of age and sex. My dataset is "full" and has age and sex coded as, "age" and "sex", respectively. Each patient is identified by an ID value ("id"). I have attached a current sorted output to give a sense of how the data looks and a sample of how I'd want it to look.

*How it currently looks*

```
       X        id      rec_date  age sex 
1   7987   #VALUE! 3/15/21 12:40 <NA>  NA
2      3 111113280 4/30/20 13:29   76   0 
3     11 111118200 4/30/20 13:38   68   1 
4   1503 111118200 6/12/20 15:07 <NA>  NA
5   6128 111118200  7/25/20 8:35 <NA>  NA
6   9777 111118200   9/4/20 9:57 <NA>  NA
8     12 111118880 4/30/20 13:38   73   1 
9    424 111118880 6/12/20 11:21 <NA>  NA 
10  5738 111118880  7/25/20 7:45 <NA>  NA 
11 12488 111118880   9/7/20 9:34 <NA>  NA 
12   345 111118880  12/7/20 5:25 <NA>  NA
13  7480 111118880 3/11/21 10:00 <NA>  NA
```

*How I want it to look*

```
       X        id      rec_date  age sex 
1   7987   #VALUE! 3/15/21 12:40 <NA>  NA
2      3 111113280 4/30/20 13:29   76   0 
3     11 111118200 4/30/20 13:38   68   1 
4   1503 111118200 6/12/20 15:07   68   1
5   6128 111118200  7/25/20 8:35   68   1
6   9777 111118200   9/4/20 9:57   68   1
8     12 111118880 4/30/20 13:38   73   1 
9    424 111118880 6/12/20 11:21   73   1 
10  5738 111118880  7/25/20 7:45   73   1 
11 12488 111118880   9/7/20 9:34   73   1 
12   345 111118880  12/7/20 5:25   73   1
13  7480 111118880 3/11/21 10:00   73   1
```

I'm sure it's a fairly simple solution, I'm still a novice to R and would appreciate any insights. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::fill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took me a while to work out your dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)

# set up your dummy data from raw text
df <- data.table::fread("X    id rec_day rec_time  age sex 
  7987   #VALUE! 3/15/21 12:40 <NA>  NA
     3 111113280 4/30/20 13:29   76   0 
    11 111118200 4/30/20 13:38   68   1 
  1503 111118200 6/12/20 15:07  NA  NA
  6128 111118200  7/25/20 8:35  NA  NA
  9777 111118200   9/4/20 9:57  NA  NA
    12 111118880 4/30/20 13:38   73   1 
   424 111118880 6/12/20 11:21  NA  NA 
  5738 111118880  7/25/20 7:45  NA  NA 
 12488 111118880   9/7/20 9:34  NA  NA 
   345 111118880  12/7/20 5:25  NA  NA
  7480 111118880 3/11/21 10:00  NA  NA") %>%
      tidyr::unite("rec_date", rec_day:rec_time, remove = TRUE, sep = " ") %>%
      dplyr::mutate(rec_date = lubridate::mdy_hm(rec_date))

df %>%
    # make sure everything is orderes (rec_date needs to be date with time format)
    dplyr::arrange(id, rec_date) %>%
    # build grouping to limit the imputation per id
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    # fill the data down wards
    tidyr::fill_(c("age","sex"), .direction = "down") %>%
    # if needed you could also fill in the other direction
    tidyr::fill_(c("age","sex"), .direction = "up") %>%
    # release grouping to avoid unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning how to work with the various functions of tidyverse but this is very helpful.